# Grading program having problems with while loop and using different data types

Tags: python

I'm making a program where I need to have the user input a series of homework grades (ranging from 0 to 10) until they type 'done' in which case I must calculate the average of the scores and provide a corresponding letter grade. My trouble is, I don't know how to calculate the average when I don't have the exact number of homeworks to divide the sum of all of the homeworks by, since it's not on a finite loop. And also, when I run my program I keep getting an error message that says TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()

Here's my code so far:

```
    print("Enter your homework scores one at a time, must be an integer ranging from 0 to 10. When finished, type done.")
number=input("Enter your homework grade: ")

while number != 'done':
    number=input("Enter your homework grade: ")
    percentage= number*10 #I need to divide by number of homeworks there are, but I'm not sure how to get the variable I need to divide by.

    if number < 0 or number > 10:
        print("Score must be between 0 and 10")
    elif percentage >= 92 and number < 100:
        letter = 'A'
    elif percentage >= 87 and number < 92:
        letter = 'B+'
    elif percentage >= 80 and number < 87:
        letter = 'B'
    elif percentage >=77 and number < 80:
        letter = 'C+'
    elif percentage >=70 and number < 77:
        letter = 'C'
    elif percentage >= 67 and number < 70:
        letter = 'D+'
    elif percentage >= 60 and number < 67:
        letter = 'D'
    elif percentage < 60 and number >= 0:
        letter= 'F'
    elif number == 'done':
        print(percentage,"%, you got an ", letter)
    else:
        print("Error: please enter an integer ranging from 0 and 10.")
```

Answer (score 0):

The input is a string type so you must explicitly convert it to an integer using something like "number = int(number)".

You could create a separate counting variable that is incremented each time through the loop, and then use that final value to divide when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of your `while` loop, you can keep an array of grades you've seen so far. It will start out empty.

```
arr = []
```

Every time you see a new grade, you can append it to the array.

```
newGrade = input("Enter your homework grade")
arr.append(float(newGrade)*10)
```

Once the user enters done, you can calculate the average using the `sum` and `len` functions, which give you the sum of the elements in the array and the number of elements in the array, respectively.

```
average = sum(arr)/len(arr)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not really supposed to use too many different functions like the ones you suggested, but I appreciate the input nontheless!

Answer (score 0):

Kevin's tells you to make an integer, say count = 0, and increment it every time you ask for a grade.

In the end, you take the sum / count.

Here is a slightly improved way on top of that:
start with count = 0

```
 Do:
    Ask for grade
    AVG = (AVG*count + new grade)/(count+1)
    count++
```

The AVG*count gives you the previous sum.